# TypeScript class inheritance behaving differently than its ES6 equivalent

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, prototype

I'm building an error handling middleware for a node.js with express and TypeScript project. Within it I have a `AppError` class that extends `Error`. It looks like this:

```
class AppError extends Error {
  public readonly internalCode: number | undefined;

  public readonly httpCode: number;

  public readonly message: string;

  constructor(httpCode: number, message: string, internalCode?: number) {
    super();
    this.internalCode = internalCode;
    this.message = message;
    this.httpCode = httpCode;
  }

  public generateReport(): GenericReport {
    return {
      code: this.internalCode,
      message: this.message,
    };
  }
}
```

I'm currently throwing `new AppError()` inside a `/error` route to catch it with the following middleware, `errorHandler`:

```
function errorHandler(err: Error, request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction,): Response {
  if (err instanceof AppError) {
    const report = err.generateReport();

    return response.status(err.httpCode).json(report);
  }

  return response.status(500).json(err);
}
```

Inside the middleware I'm trying to find `AppError` on `err` [[Prototype]] chain, but the verification always fails in the TypeScript code. However, after transpiling it with Babel and running the JS version with `node`, `err instanceof AppError` resolves to `true`. Why doesn't it in the TS code?

In the example above, `Object.getPrototypeOf(err)` returns me `Error {}`, and changing `err` type to `AppError` or `any` doesn't affect the result.

To my understanding, the newly constructed object (after `new AppError()` runs) should be [[Prototype]]-linked to `AppError`. And running `curl http://localhost:3333/error` with the TS server on, I get `{ "internalCode": 1, "message": "This is an error", "httpCode": 500 }`, which means that `err` is indeed created by `AppError()`.

There's a working example of the problem in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/sndmnn/code-example). Any clarification on this topic will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean fails in the typescript code? You don't really run typescript code. It gets converted to Javascript. Have you looked at the output? Might give you a hint. It might be problematic that your output is `es5` which is before classes where a thing.

Comment: @Evert yeah... that was my problem. I had es5 as target in the tsconfig. Thank you very much. I've spent the las hour on this, and it haven't even gone through my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your code. A few comments:

1. Switching to a later ecmascript output might fix this, as your output does not generate classes right now, because EcmaScript 5 didn't have them yet.
2. It's a good idea to *not* use ts-node tools, especially when you're trying to debug something like. It can give funky result, and it's nice to just be able to look at the real javascript being executed.
3. I took a look at your repo, and I believe that you should probably just use `instanceof` for what you are trying to do. I think for the purpose of your error middleware, instanceof makes a bit more sense.

If you're interested, I also wrote an error handling middleware that does a similar thing:

https://github.com/curveball/problem/blob/master/src/index.ts